# Why is $ \lim_{m \to \infty}P(|Y|>m)=0$ where $Y$ is any random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Why is $$ \lim_{m \to \infty}P(|Y|>m)=0?$$

Why would this hold if say $A=\{|Y|=\infty\}$ has a strictly positive measure? Wouldn't the limit in such a case be equal to $P(A)$

Why is $ \lim_{m \to \infty}P(|Y|>m)$ different from  $ \lim_{m \to \infty}P(|Y|\ge m)$?

I am really confused

Comment: What is the source of the claim $\lim_{m\to \infty} \mathbb{P}(|Y|>m)=0$ for any $Y$? Intuitively, it’s contradictory to have $\mathbb{P}(|Y|=\infty)>0$ but the former limit vanish...

Comment: Of course this holds if $Y$ is almost-surely finite. In most cases, random variables (RV) simply refer to our good old $\mathbb{R}$-valued RVs and so the claim holds. But sometimes, especially in limit theorems, $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued RVs are considered without being explicitly mentioned. I would not say this is a good practice, but this abuse is easily identifiable from the context, so it seems that people choose to bear with it...

Answer (score 1):

By definition a random variable takes values in $\mathbb R$. [The statement that   $P(|Y| >m) \to 0$ is made in this context,though some people use a more general definition of  a random variable. If you allow infinite values then these limits need not be $0$].  So the question of $Y$ being $\infty$ does not arise. Also $P(|Y| >m)$ and $P(|Y| \geq m)$ both have limit $0$ since these events decrease to the empty set as $m$ increases to $\infty$. .

Comment: By what definition does a random variable takes values in $\mathbb R$?  I thought a random variable took values in a measurable space, which might be $\mathbb R$ and its Borel sigma-algebra or might be something else.  For example the Heads or Tails of a coin flip are not in $\mathbb R$

Comment: @Henry Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random variable If the values of $Y$ are in some measurable space an inequality like $|Y| >m$ makes no sense. So, in this context, one is talking about a 'standard definition' as in this Wikipedia article.

Comment: But you can easily use $\mathbb R \cup \{+\infty, -\infty\}$ and then have $P(|Y| >m)$ and $P(|Y| \geq m)$ making sense

Comment: RVs representing hitting times of certain states in Markov chains conventionally take values in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ as it possible to never reach a certain state.

Comment: I am a bit confused because when one says $E[|X|]<\infty$ implies $X< \infty$ a.s. But doesnt that implicitly imply that $X$ can take infinite value on a measure zero set?

Comment: Most basic books on Probability Theory consider only real valued random variables and the statement $P(|Y|>m) \to 0$ is made in this context. This limit need not be $0$ if you allow infinite values.